# Counters to calculate frequency range based on values in one column grouped by another

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, group-by, jupyter-notebook

I have a dataframe with 3 columns 'UserProduct', 'OrderDates' (sorted from max to min group-wise) & 'diff' (the difference between the first date & each of the other dates for that particular group).

I want to create 3 counters in the range'0-30', '30-60', '60-90'

Basically, I want to categorize the diff(in days) column according to the range 
(For example: if diff is in the range "0-30", counter 1 gets a vote "1"

Sample below:

---

**Input Data:**

```
       UserProduct              OrderDates       diff(in days)
0  12111211/123232   2020-03-12 17:19:16.103              0
1  12111211/123232   2020-03-12 18:10:45.974              0
2  12111211/123232   2020-03-11 17:19:16.103              1
3  12111211/123232   2020-03-10 18:10:45.974              2
4  12111211/123232   2020-03-10 18:10:45.974              2
5  165870101/73066   2020-03-12 19:49:15.752              0
6  165870101/73066   2020-02-11 19:49:15.752             31
```

---

**Expected Output:**

```
       UserProduct              OrderDates    diff(in days)     0-30      30-60   60-90
0  12111211/123232   2020-03-12 17:19:16.103              0    1+1+1=3    -        -
5  165870101/73066   2020-03-12 19:49:15.752              0     -          1        -
```

In the input data -> the first value (OrderDates) for the group 12111211/123232 is subtracted from the subsequent 4 (OrderDates) to arrive at 0,1,2,2 (in days)

---

In the output -> for the group 12111211/123232, Only the first row prevails and the subsequent diff(in days) values (all in the range 0-30) contribute to the first counter getting 1+1+1+1 = 4

---

My code to arrive at this point :

```
#to get top 5 records per user/product combination
bf_frequency =  bf.groupby(["UserProduct"])['ORDER_DATE'].nlargest(5).reset_index(name ='OrderDates') 

bf_frequency.sort_values(by=['OrderDates'],inplace=True, ascending=False)

bf_frequency['diff(in days)'] = 0

grp = bf_frequency.groupby('UserProduct')['OrderDates']

for i, group in grp:
    bf_frequency['diff(in days)'][bf_frequency.index.isin(group.index)] = group.sub(group.iloc[0])

bf_frequency['diff(in days)']= bf_frequency['diff(in days)'].dt.days.abs()
```

---

I have the output as shown in the input data, but looking to create a counter from here

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit more on how you got to `1+1+1+1`?

Comment: @JvdV - Thanks for your response, I've edited the question - hope it's clearer now

Comment: It is much clearer thanks =). I'll see if I can come up with something but someone else might be quicker/better as I'm learning Python atm

Comment: 0-30, the count must be 1+1+1 =3 right?

Comment: @G.S.J That is indeed correct, my bad . It is 1+1+1=3